Does PyPI no longer allow uploads with username and password?
I've just republished one of my packages, but to do so, I had to give the username as __token__ and use an API Token I generated from the website as my password. Is there another way to authenticate when I publish? The error reads
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19.1/19.1 kB • 00:00 • 9.0 MB/s
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details.                                                                                         
ERROR    HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/                                                                                                  
         Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.

And if I go to that help page, there is no mention of usernames or passwords, only authentication tokens.

When I logged in to my account I was made to set up 2FA and download recovery codes. That clued me in that PyPI may have decided to go all out on security. I mean, fair enough: If someone compromised a popular package and then millions of us downloaded malicious code...yeesh. All the same, I found it slightly annoying to figure out, because twine still takes a username and password.

So is the answer that there is no way to use username and password? Was there a press release about it? Please answer the question with relevant sources, and I'l accept it. It would be nice if twine were updated to reflect the change.

@PavelKomarov: twine works with third-party package indices as well (I've used it to upload packages to a corporate internal package repo), so removing that functionality would be a problem for folks who aren't publishing to PyPI itself. PyPI not supporting username/password has nothing to do with whether or not twine should support it.

I've also used it to upload to internal package repos. I guess organizations decide for themselves how secure they want to be, and PyPI is going to the max, which makes some sense. I just didn't get the memo.

I believe you can use .pypirc and a username and password to publish the package.

Yes, you should generate an API token and set the username to __token__ in your configuration files. It has been that way for some time now.
Announced here on PyPI.org, here on python.org.
There is Use API tokens by default for PyPI #561 issue on twine for tracking a better UX there.  twine still takes a username and password and basic auth can not be removed altogether because of non-PyPI destinations.

Since January 1st isn't so long. Not surprised I ran in to this now. I've gone around linking some other questions which surfaced first to this question, so hopefully others will find your answer.
